# Storing unix timestamp in sql

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, unix-timestamp

I have a unix date in `long` format

```
Long tmpLong = (Long) local.getValue();
```

Here is the value of tmpLong

> 1485710457166

Now I want to store this variable inside of my SQLite DB, after some research I found out that you cant store Longs in SQLite so I tried this:

```
Long tmpLong = (Long) local.getValue();
Integer tmpInt = tmpLong.intValue();
```

But this gives me:

> -348227250

In SQLite my datatype is `INTEGER`

I need help storing this unix number, any help is appreciated

**Update 1**

If I try store it as a long, so

```
localDB.add(image_id, unixTimestamp, PATH);
```

And then in my add method (inside SQLiteHelper class). I print the value for testing :

```
 public void add(String image_id, Long date, String path) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("SQL", "date " + date);
```

It prints `1`

> D/SQL: date 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is what will happen when you truncate a 64 bit Long into a 32 bits integer...

Dont do that but try to store it like it is (as a long) because SQLite ints can handle that values, take a look into the [Datatypes In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

[image]

## Edit:

Your code below:

```
public void add(String image_id, Long date, String path) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("SQL", "date " + date);
}
```

if that code is so as it is posted then you are passing as parameter **1** for the date value... the method **this.getWritableDatabase();** is not going to modify/change the value of the date parameter...

Comment: well, before the data is sent to that class I check the unix value and its correct, when it gets to the next class its `1` which i know doesnt make any sense

Comment: nevermind I found the problem =, it was not to do with the date